# Javascript pack int?

Tags: javascript

```
var data1 = document.getElementById("data1").value;
var data2 = document.getElementById("data2").value;
```

Assuming the data2 contains some text and data1 contains only values from "0"-"255", how can I "combine" those?

Expected result: [single byte][data2]
What I got using `data1+data2`: [1-3 bytes][data2]

In C and C++:

```
unsigned char int_1 = 245;
unsigned char data[100];
//fill data with text but leave pos 0 empty
data[0] = int_1 ;
```

In PHP:

```
$data2 = pack("C", $data1).$data2;
```

Comment: Can you explain with some actual example?

Comment: what do you mean by 'combine'? If you have a string that's a number you van user parseInt to make it an integer. parseInt("10") will become 10.

Comment: u need the ascii code for data2 var..

Comment: This is confusing, what is [data2] ?

Comment: Sorry, added c++ example.

Comment: Ok so, if I get it right you want to pack data1 into data2 string ?

Comment: yes, like the PHP function pack("C", data1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if I got it right, this is what you need

```
var finalData = String.fromCharCode(data1) + data2;
```

OR if you want to replace first char of data2

```
var finalData = String.fromCharCode(data1) + data2.substr(1);
```

**EDIT:** No need to use `parseInt` thanks to [prinzhorn's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422124/prinzhorn) comment

Comment: `String.fromCharCode('65') === String.fromCharCode(65)`

Comment: Oh I got your point. I'll update my answer accordingly to this.

Answer (score 1):

try
 `parseInt(data1)+parseInt(data2);`

Comment: data2 is not int. Also I tried parseInt(data1)+data2 but got the same result

Comment: data2 will be something like "256" or "xyz"? if it's a number in string like "256" it'll work